# java how to share field and method between classes

Tags: java, spring, jackson, swagger, springfox

I have some BaseX pojo class ex:

```java
public class Base1 {
    private String base1Field1;
    private String base1Field2;
    // getter & setter
}
public class Base2 {
    private String base2Field1;
    private String base2Field2;
    // getter & setter
}
```

And some DomainVo pojo class, it has some field & method from BaseX class ex:

```java
//from base1
public class Domain1Vo {
    private String domain1Field1;
    private String base1Field1;
    private String base1Field2;
    // getter & setter
}
//from base1 & base 2
public class Domain2Vo {
    private String domain2Field1;
    private String base1Field1;
    private String base1Field2;
    private String base2Field1;
    private String base2Field2;
    // getter & setter
}
```

I don't want copy paste those fields from `BaseX` class to my domain object, but I can't use `extends Base1, Base2` because java don't allow it.

I don't actually use `BaseX` in my code, I define them just want a single place to maintain those field.

update:
I can't change my domain object structure, because it's come from/to other service as json. Also I need use it to generate a swagger doc(I use springfox). This why I need both field & method.

======== some research I did

I found a lib called **lombok**, it has a feature name `@Delegate`
https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate

```java
//from base1
public class Domain1Vo {
    private String domain1Field1;
    @Delegate
    private Base1 base1;
    // getter & setter
}
```

It can generate method from `BaseX` class, but not field.

Comment: You can make your domain classes contain instances of the base classes

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you need to fuse the fields, getters and setters into one class? There is a design guideline called "composition over inheritance". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance
Maybe your solution is to wrap Base1 and Base2, instead of extending them?

Comment: I can't change the domain object, check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Composition is what you want. Inheritance is wildly overused (also getters and, especially, setters).

The base classes become components. (Use better names! Even "base" isn't a useful word to use in a class name.)

```
public final class Component1 {
    private String component1Field1;
    private String component1Field2;
    // domain methods
}
public final class Component2 {
    private String component2Field1;
    private String component2Field2;
}

public final class Domain1Vo {
    private String domain1Field1;
    private final Component1 component1;
    public Domain1Vo(
        Component1 component1
    ) {
        // Or construct.
        this.component1 =
           Objects.requireNonNull(component1);
    }
    // domain methods
}
//from base1 & base 2
public final class Domain2Vo {
    private String domain2Field1;
    private final Component1 component1;
    private final Component2 component2;
    public Domain2Vo(
        Component1 component1,
        Component2 component2,
    ) {
        // Or construct.
        this.component1 =
           Objects.requireNonNull(component1);
        this.component2 =
           Objects.requireNonNull(component2);
    }
    // domain methods
}
```

Comment: I can't change my domain object structure, because it's come from/to other service as json. Also I need use it to generate a swagger doc(springfox). This why I need both field & method.